# Out of memory error inside fragments on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

When I test my app, I noticed in the Profiler the presence of 3 memory leaks, all related to fragments I put into the app. Reading other questions here, several times it was suggested to compress the images in the app (I have 2 of them), so I tried both compressing or deleting them completely, without success... I'm still quite new to app development, so I'm still not sure how to go about troubleshooting this kind of problems...

Here's the code for the MainActivity:

```
package com.pierfrancescofrezza.vivibusso

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
    private val categoriesFragment = CategoriesFragment()
    private val galleryFragment = GalleryFragment()
    private val searchFragment = SearchFragment()

    var context = this

    private val networkMonitor = NetworkMonitorUtil(this)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        checkConnectivity()
        replaceFragment(homeFragment)
        navbar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.navigation_home -> replaceFragment(homeFragment)
                R.id.navigation_categories -> replaceFragment(categoriesFragment)
                R.id.navigation_gallery -> replaceFragment(galleryFragment)
                R.id.navigation_search -> replaceFragment(searchFragment)
            }
            true
        }
        val screenLayoutSize =
            resources.configuration.screenLayout and Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK
        if (screenLayoutSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL || screenLayoutSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
            requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
        }

        networkMonitor.result = { isAvailable, type ->
            runOnUiThread {
                when (isAvailable) {
                    true -> {
                        when (type) {
                            ConnectionType.Wifi -> {
                                Log.i("NETWORK_MONITOR_STATUS", "Wifi Connection")
                                wifiButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_wifi_24)
                                wifiButton.setOnClickListener {
                                    displayToast(getString(R.string.wifi_status_on))
                                }
                            }
                            ConnectionType.Cellular -> {
                                Log.i("NETWORK_MONITOR_STATUS", "Cellular Connection")
                                wifiButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_wifi_24)
                                wifiButton.setOnClickListener {
                                    displayToast(getString(R.string.wifi_status_on))
                                }
                            }
                            else -> { }
                        }
                    }
                    false -> {
                        Log.i("NETWORK_MONITOR_STATUS", "No Connection")
                        wifiButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_wifi_off_24)
                        wifiButton.setOnClickListener {
                            displayToast(getString(R.string.wifi_status_off))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        networkMonitor.register()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        networkMonitor.unregister()
    }

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        transaction.commit()
    }

    private fun displayToast(message: String?) {
        val wifiToast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        wifiToast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 150)
        wifiToast.show()
    }

    fun openInfo(view: View) {
        val intent = Intent(this, InfoActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun checkConnectivity() {
        val manager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val activeNetwork = manager.activeNetworkInfo
        if (null == activeNetwork) {
            AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.warning)
                .setMessage(R.string.wifi_status_off)
                .setPositiveButton("Retry") { _, _ ->
                    recreate()
                }
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { _, _ ->
                    finish()
                }
                .show()
        }
    }
}
```

...the code for every fragment that has the memory leak...

```
package com.pierfrancescofrezza.vivibusso

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.webkit.WebSettings
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.webkit.WebSettingsCompat
import androidx.webkit.WebViewFeature
import java.util.*

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [CategoriesFragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class CategoriesFragment : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val catWebView: WebView = view.findViewById(R.id.webViewCategories)
        catWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView,
                url: String
            ): Boolean {
                if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") || url.startsWith("smsto:") || url.startsWith(
                        "mailto:"
                    ) || url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mmsto:")
                ) {
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                    startActivity(intent)
                    return true
                } else {
                    view.loadUrl(url)
                }
                return true
            }
        }

        val catLang = Locale.getDefault().language
        if (catLang == "it") {
            catWebView.loadUrl("https://vivibusso.app/android/it/categories/categories.html")
        } else {
            catWebView.loadUrl("https://vivibusso.app/android/en/categories/categories.html")
        }

        catWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        catWebView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE

        catWebView.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                val webView = v as WebView
                when (keyCode) {
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK -> if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack()
                    }
                }
            }
            true
        }

        if (WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.FORCE_DARK)) {
            when (resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {
                    WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(catWebView.settings,
                        WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_ON
                    )
                }
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO, Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED -> {
                    WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(catWebView.settings,
                        WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_OFF
                    )
                }
                else -> {
                    //
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment CategoriesFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            CategoriesFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

```
package com.pierfrancescofrezza.vivibusso

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.KeyEvent
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.webkit.WebSettings
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.webkit.WebSettingsCompat
import androidx.webkit.WebViewFeature
import java.util.*

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [GalleryFragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val galWebView: WebView = view.findViewById(R.id.webViewGallery)
        galWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView,
                url: String
            ): Boolean {
                if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") || url.startsWith("smsto:") || url.startsWith(
                        "mailto:"
                    ) || url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mmsto:")
                ) {
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                    startActivity(intent)
                    return true
                } else {
                    view.loadUrl(url)
                }
                return true
            }
        }

        val galLang = Locale.getDefault().language
        if (galLang == "it") {
            galWebView.loadUrl("https://vivibusso.app/android/it/gallery/gallery.html")
        } else {
            galWebView.loadUrl("https://vivibusso.app/android/en/gallery/gallery.html")
        }

        galWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        galWebView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
        galWebView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
        galWebView.settings.displayZoomControls = false

        galWebView.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                val webView = v as WebView
                when (keyCode) {
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK -> if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack()
                    }
                }
            }
            true
        }

        if (WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.FORCE_DARK)) {
            when (resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {
                    WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(galWebView.settings,
                        WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_ON
                    )
                }
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO, Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED -> {
                    WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(galWebView.settings,
                        WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_OFF
                    )
                }
                else -> {
                    //
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment GalleryFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            GalleryFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

```
package com.pierfrancescofrezza.vivibusso

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.KeyEvent
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.webkit.WebSettings
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.webkit.WebSettingsCompat
import androidx.webkit.WebViewFeature
import java.util.*

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [SearchFragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class SearchFragment : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val srcWebView: WebView = view.findViewById(R.id.webViewSearch)
        srcWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView,
                url: String
            ): Boolean {
                if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") || url.startsWith("smsto:") || url.startsWith(
                        "mailto:"
                    ) || url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mmsto:")
                ) {
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                    startActivity(intent)
                    return true
                } else {
                    view.loadUrl(url)
                }
                return true
            }
        }

        val srcLang = Locale.getDefault().language
        if (srcLang == "it") {
            srcWebView.loadUrl("https://vivibusso.app/android/it/search.html")
        } else {
            srcWebView.loadUrl("https://vivibusso.app/android/en/search.html")
        }

        srcWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        srcWebView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
        srcWebView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
        srcWebView.settings.displayZoomControls = false

        srcWebView.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                val webView = v as WebView
                when (keyCode) {
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK -> if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack()
                    }
                }
            }
            true
        }

        if (WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.FORCE_DARK)) {
            when (resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {
                    WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(srcWebView.settings,
                        WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_ON
                    )
                }
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO, Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED -> {
                    WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(srcWebView.settings,
                        WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_OFF
                    )
                }
                else -> {
                    //
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment SearchFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            SearchFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

...and here's the error message I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.pierfrancescofrezza.vivibusso, PID: 4548
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 62720012 byte allocation with 1273652 free bytes and 46MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:455)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:144)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:63)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:82)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:69)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:199)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:119)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1551)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1602)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.pierfrancescofrezza.vivibusso.LaunchActivity.onCreate(LaunchActivity.kt:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Please write a comment if you need other parts of the code, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 62720012 byte allocation
 with 1273652 free bytes and 46MB until OOM
```

Your error is about excessive memory use - it's trying to allocate memory for a ~63MB bitmap when you only have 46MB free (OOM means an *Out Of Memory error*). It's possible you have memory leaks eating up some precious memory, but a 63MB bitmap is pretty big (it's about 500x500 for a 32-bit image) and you shouldn't really have too many things that size in memory.

If you only have *two*, and they're similar sizes then *maybe* it's ok? Depends on the device (how much memory it actually has) as well as what the rest of the app is doing. [Here's a section of the docs about handling large bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap) - as you can see they recommend using an image-loading library that will handle things like caching, and also resizing so the bitmap will only be stored as big as it needs to be.

But yeah, ideally your images will be an appropriate size to begin with - if you have an icon, or an avatar that's being displayed, it shouldn't be kept in memory as a huge original. If you need the huge version, you can load that when it's needed (which is where the image libraries come in!). If it's an icon or something that's always small, it's better to provide an appropriately sized version in the first place. [There's a whole section on doing this for resources](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp), or use vector images where possible (they scale nicely and don't take up much size in the app)

---

A memory **leak** is where you're losing memory that should have been recovered, usually because something that should have been destroyed is being kept alive by another component that's hanging onto it. I can't see anything obvious from looking at your code, but I don't have time to really dig into it.

[Here's the docs for the memory profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler) - there's a lot to read, but if you do a GC (garbage collection) and then a Heap Dump, you can inspect all the objects in memory. If you arrange all the objects by package, it'll be easier to find the stuff in your app, then see if you have too many of a certain thing (like more than one of each of your Fragments). If you click on those instances, you can see what's holding a reference to them, and that can help you track down which ones should have been released and what's keeping them alive.

You could also try [LeakCanary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/) but I don't have as much experience with that. These are all good skills to learn though!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried LeakCanary, it detected 5 memory leaks, 4 into the fragments, and the other one as I understand it seems to be about the images I put into the app. Regarding the fragments, it seems that the onDestroyView function is missing; I had suspected something like that, but since I didn't know how to implement that type of function yet - and since everything worked fine - I had given up. As for the images, it's very strange, since the images I put are heavily compressed and together they took just under a megabyte of space. At this point I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Another strange thing I noticed is the fact that the OOM error only appears testing the app on the emulator - only on specific versions of Android (6.0/7.0/8.0), but not on a physical device.

Comment: @pierofrezza I didn't mention it explicitly, but compression doesn't matter - that's just for the filesize. When it's actually turned into a bitmap in memory it uses *width x height x bits-per-pixel* bits, which means it's purely about the dimensions of the image and its bit-depth (ARGB888 by default on Android i.e. 32-bit). That's why avoiding large images, and using an image-loading library that can cache/discard images for you is important. At a guess, you're out of memory on the emulator because by default virtual devices are configured with pretty low memory compared to a modern phone

Comment: As for `onDestroyView`, that's a lifecycle callback in a `Fragment` that gets called when its *view* (its displayed layout hierarchy) is destroyed - the `Fragment` itself can outlive its view, so it's important not to hold onto view stuff after `onDestroyView` is called. One typical scenario for this is if you're using *view binding* - you want to drop any reference to the inflated *binding* object when the view is destroyed (example here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments). If you don't have anything to do though, you don't need to override `onDestroyView`

Comment: That's strange, if I recall correctly when I was working a year ago on this app when I tried on the emulator it always works fine, maybe it's a bug in the latest version of Android Studio, but I'm just guessing...
Regarding the fragments, could you suggest where to modify based on the code I posted in the question?

Comment: @pierofrezza I can't see anything in the code you posted that suggests the need for overriding `onDestroyView`, you'd have to dig into why LeakCanary is suggesting it! Either way, the reason you're getting that crash is because you don't have enough memory left to load that large image, and I doubt a few `View`s floating about the place are going to take up much memory - unless they're `ImageView`s containing large bitmaps. Keeping all four `Fragment` instances in memory (via variables) in your `Activity` might not be helping either. Only way to know is to use the profiler and look at mem use

Comment: OK, thank you for the advice, now I just have to investigate further, sooner or later I'll come to a solution... Thank you again!